# How to activate (or inactivate) cuts in Gurobi, with python? And where do I find a documentation of these cuts?

Tags: python, gurobi, branch-and-bound

I'm trying to adapt a model, using python, and trying to improve it by inactivate and activate some heuristics of B&C. For that, I'm looking for some help with how to manage parameters for cut heuristics and what types do I have in Gurobi.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can influence cuts and heuristics by [setting parameters](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/py_model_setparam.html).  There is an extensive list of parameters in the [documentation](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/py_model_setparam.html).  For example, to disable cut generation and heuristics for a given model you can do

```
import gurobipy as gp
m = gp.Model()
m.setParam(GRB.Param.cuts, 0)
m.setParam(GRB.Param.heuristics, 0.0)
```